# Is there a simpler way to do this?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way I can loop through the cell letters instead of copy pasting and changing the cells?

Perhaps with an array?

I work in education, and these google sheets keep needing to be altered at my work and the following is how I have been doing it.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange("B21").setValue('3');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('B22').setValue('MT1');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('C22').setFormula('=C33'); 
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('C21').setValue(' ');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange("E21").setValue('3');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('E22').setValue('MT1');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('F22').setFormula('=f33'); 
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('F21').setValue(' ');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange("H21").setValue('3');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('H22').setValue('MT1');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('I22').setFormula('=I33'); 
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('I21').setValue(' ');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange("K21").setValue('3');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('K22').setValue('MT1');
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('L22').setFormula('=L33'); 
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('L21').setValue(' ');

 }
```

Comment: an overall array will need continuous cells, what do you have for example inD21:D22?

Comment: I need to skip D and every third letter after that

Comment: so, adapt my answer for each group of 4 continuous cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script I wrote that should work for you:

```js
function setValues() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet =  spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange('B21:L22');
  var rangeArray = range.getValues();

  let ignoreCol = ['D','G','J']; //Ignore columns D, G, J
  
  for(var i in rangeArray) {
    //loop starts by going through rows, focusing on one row at a time.

    for(var j in rangeArray[i]) {
      //within each row, it calls each column.
      var val;

      let ix = Number(i) + Number(range.getRowIndex());
      let jx = Number(j) + Number(range.getColumn());
      let a1Range = sheet.getRange(ix,jx).getA1Notation();
      let colCheck = a1Range.slice(0,1); //Gets the column letter

      if(i == 0 && (j % 3 == 0 || j == 0)) val = '3';
      else if(i == 0) val = ' ';
      if(i == 1 && (j % 3 == 0 || j == 0)) val = `MT1`;
      else if(i == 1) val = `=${colCheck}33`;

      if(!ignoreCol.includes(colCheck)) { //Only moves on if the column is not ignored.
        sheet.getRange(ix,jx).setValue(val);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I ran it a few times and it seems to be working properly.

[image: ex]

Please let me know if you have any issues with this, or would like something explained.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
var sh = spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

sh.getRange("B21:C22").setValues([['3','MT1'],[' ','=C33']])
sh.getRange("E21:F22").setValues([['3','MT1'],[' ','=F33']])
sh.getRange("H21:I22").setValues([['3','MT1'],[' ','=I33']])
sh.getRange("K21:L22").setValues([['3','MT1'],[' ','=L33']])
```